# I have Metal.framework error in SelectRenderingAPIImpl() script

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, metal

[Error is shown in picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PDQq.png) I need to run Unity project in XCode. I try with 7-8 Unity versions, and macOS Monterey, macOS Ventura. I have Metal.framework Assertion failed error in SelectRenderingAPIImple() script. I looking for information about it 2 weeks, didn't find any information about it. Earlier I just run, and everything is worked. Please help me!

I need to run Unity project in XCode

Comment: Make sure you are properly initializing _MetalDevice and _MetalCommadQueue. One or both of those are nil. My guess is you are forgetting a step.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock can you explain if you know? _MetalDevice and _MetalCommandQueue are standard things of Unity, how I influence to them? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I have never used Unity so I don't know. It seems like you must be missing an initializing step or something since those properties are nil.

Comment: What is your target device?

Comment: @HamidYusifli thank you for comment. Target device is simulator in Xcode